# Problem to integrate the function to transform Kelvin in Celsius

Tags: javascript, function, transform, openweathermap

I'm having problem to integrate the function to transform Kelvin in Celsius, can someone help? I'm pretty new to this world, be kind! :)

What can I do to transform it in celsius?

```
let key = ...........

let requestCity = async (city) => {
    let url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
    let query = '?q=' + city + '&appid=' + key;
    let response = await fetch(url + query);
    let data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

let searchForm = document.querySelector('.search-location');
let cityValue = document.querySelector('.search-location input');
let cityName = document.querySelector('.city-name p');
let condition = document.querySelector('.condition');
let temp = document.querySelector('.temp')
let high = document.querySelector('.high')
let low = document.querySelector('.low')
let hum = document.querySelector('.hum')
let feel = document.querySelector('.feel')
// let celsius = (kelvin) => {
//     celsius = math.round(kelvin - 273.15);
//     return celsius
// }
updateWeather = (city) => {
    cityName.textContent = city.name;
    condition.innerHTML = city.weather[0].description;
    temp.innerHTML = city.main.temp + '&deg;K';
    high.innerHTML = city.main.temp_max + '&deg;K'
    low.innerHTML = city.main.temp_min + '&deg;K'
    hum.innerHTML = city.main.humidity + '%'
    feel.innerHTML = city.main.feels_like + '&deg;K'

}

searchForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let citySearched = cityValue.value;
    console.log(citySearched);
    searchForm.reset();
    requestCity(citySearched)
        .then((data) => { updateWeather(data) })
        .catch((error) => { console.log(error) })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula to translate Kelvin to Celsius (essentially just subtract 273.15 from your Kelvin degrees to get the Celsius counterpart).

Here is a little block of code I wrote, so you can get the idea:

```
function toCelsius(kelvin) {
    if(Number.isFinite(kelvin)) { // Checking if kelvin is a number.
        const KELVIN_CELSIUS_DIFF = 273.15; // maybe unnecessary here, but it is good practice to avoid magic numbers.
        let celsius = kelvin - KELVIN_CELSIUS_DIFF;
        return celsius; // could also be just return kelvin - KELVIN_CELSIUS_DIFF;
    } else {
        // kelvin is not a number, should be handled.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank, anyway i haven’t been clear with my question. I’m having problems integrating the function toCelsius in the updateWeather..... innerHTML.....

Comment: You don't have to convert between kelvin and celcius for this task, you could just add "&units=metric" or "&units=kelvin" to the API call